# Most PowerApps users getting error "you don't have permission to view this data"

Tags: authentication, powerapps

I am a beginner in powerapps. I am trying to create app which can be used by employees of my organization and all are having Office 365 accounts. I have shared app with all user but only 3 users (including myself) are able to work on apps and other users are getting below error on first screen of my app.

Error occurred when user open app:

> you don't have permission to view this data. server response : The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme "Anonymous".The authentication  header received from server was 'browser error in powerApps

Comment: What kind of data is your app using? In addition to sharing the app, did you make sure that all your users have access to that data?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to access MS Outlook and MS Teams.  The error is extremely misleading.  The problem was NOT that some administrator had disabled access in certain situations.   The problem was resolved by going to the windows "Credential Manager" and deleting all the old credentials, forcing the MS apps to log you in again, and that then allows me to access those systems.

No idea if this is your situation or not, but anyone receiving this error should first try deleting all the old credentials for that service.

Answer (score 0):

This typically means that your users do not have access to a Data Source *used* by the PowerApp.

When you click `File/Share` and enter a person/groups name, you will see on the right hand side something to the effect of:

**Here are all the data sources your users will need permission to.**

Heed this. Otherwise issues like this will ensue.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I encounter this problem, I just go to the SharePoint site, explore the site permissions from the setting, and add the user to the pre-created SharePoint site members group.